# OpenGL very large mesh clipping

Tags: java, opengl-es, lwjgl, mesh, clipping

For my work I had to get into OpenGL 3d rendering recently, and I admit I'm quite new to this topic.

Without getting into too much detail, I have to deal with a HUGE array of data (vertices) from which I need to draw a shape. Basically, think of a plane of a very odd shape in 3d space. This shape is being added to on the fly. Think of a car moving on a plane and painting it's trail behind it - but not just a simple trail, but with holes, discarded sections, etc. And it generates a new section several times per second for hours.

So, obviously, what you end up with is A LOT of vertices, that do get optimized somewhat, but not enough. Millions of them.
And obviously I can't just feed it to a GPU of embedded system as a vertex VBO.
So I've been reading about culling and clipping, and as far as I understand I only need to display the visible triangles of this array, and not render everything else.

Now, how do I do that properly?

The simplest brute-force solution would be to go through all triangles, and if they lie outside of frustum - just not draw them. Generate a buffer of what I DO draw and pass it to GPU

One idea I had is to divide world space into squares, a kind of chunks, and basically split the "trail" mesh between them. So each square will hold data for it's part of the trail, and then I could use frustum culling, maybe, to decide which squares to render and which to skip. 
But I'm not convinced it's a great solution. I also read that you should reduce the number of GL function calls as much as possible, and calling it for hundreds of squares doesn't seem great.

So I decided to ask for advice among people who would understand the subject better then me. Sadly, I don't get much learning time - I need to dive right into it.
If anyone could give me some directed tips it'd be appreciated.

Comment: One other idea I've had is to maybe forget drawing actual triangles, and instead use a texture cast onto a "floor" plane. As the object moves, the texture gets updated. Then I could have several such textures to keep their size manageable, and load them dynamically when needed (keep no more than 9 such "tiles" loaded at any given time, to fill the space all around the object. I'm not sure if that'd be faster or slower than drawing the mesh. And resolution is also a concern - I expect it'd produce pixellation if the camera gets too close to the texture.

Answer (score 2):

You'd be better off using some form of spatial partitioning tree (e.g. OctTree, QuadTree, etc). That's a similar approach to your second suggestion, however because it's hierarchical, searching the tree is O(logN) vs O(n).

Comment: Yes, that's a great suggestion to optimize my idea. If I go that way, I'll definitely use something like that!